# Cypress is not working on custom commands

Tags: cypress

I create a new file under support/header.js to reuse for checking headers i also import it to e2e.js

header.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('checkHeader',() => {

    //* FAVICON
    it('Check Favicon 1', () => {
        cy.get('head link[type="image/png"]') 
          .should('have.attr', 'href') 
          .and('eq', '/favicon-32x32.png?v=26696447bf4055aecabfb5be2539b037');
    });
});
```

and i'm importing it to a test e2e/test-header.cy.js

```
describe('Header', () => {

    //* VISIT THE WEBPAGE
    it('Visit the website', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl'));
        
    });

    it('Check Header', () => {
        cy.checkHeader();
    });
});
```

When i'm running the test it's doing nothing.

[image: test-result]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put an `it()` inside a command. Commands are the building blocks of `it()` not the other way round.

With that structure, you are trying to build nested `it()` which is also not possible.

```js
it('Check Header', () => {

   //cy.checkHeader();
   it('Check Favicon 1', () => {
     cy.get(...

})
```

Just remove that inner `it()` and it will work perfectly.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('checkHeader',() => {
   cy.log('Check Favicon 1')
   cy.get('head link...
});

it('Check Header', () => {
  cy.checkHeader();
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It's now working I'm just trying to organize the test as much as possible. I tried to replace the it to describe and it's accepted by the custom command. Thank you!